# Make selected option persistent for session

Tags: javascript, session-variables

I have a filter that uses a select for the user to pick a value.

Using javascript, is it possible to set the selection as a "session" variable so that when the user reloads/revisits that page their previous filter is already picked?

This should not persist after the user closes their browser, just like a PHP session would.

Sample Select box markup:

```
<select name="filter-with" class="filter-with">
                    <option value="">Select . . .</option>
                    <option value="demo">Session</option>
                    <option value="ambassador">Ambassador</option>
                    <option value="customer_coordinator">Customer Coordinator</option>
                    <option value="account_prime">Account Prime</option>
                    <option value="marketing_prime">Host</option>
                </select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to differentiate between "user closes their browser" and "user closes this tab"?

Comment: if they close the tab it should reset. Basically I want to persist if they hit the back button.

Comment: There are two options:
1)in javascript side you can use sessionStorage
2)in PHP side, you capture the onchange event of the select element and then using ajax to submit the value to PHP to save the value to PHP session variable.

Comment: I don't have access to PHP unfortunately. sessionStorage sounds like exactly what the doctor ordered!